# I have created a new android project and it has buildconfig.java in gen folder

Tags: android

I have tried to clean it, reinstall it.
But, Everything went in vain, R.java file is not creating 
I am working with the same configuration on another computer its working pretty well so i don't know where the problem lies.
BuildConfig.java doesn't diappears and R.java doesn't appears...

Comment: create a new Project & paste the java files & xml in that new Project..

Answer (score 1):

try to delete `BuildConfig.java` and `R.java` and re build